# Yii 2 registerJs in twig templates

Tags: twig, yii2

In the [Yii 2.0 guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-template-engines.html) it says you can register Javascript code in a twig template like this:

```
{registerJs key='show' position='POS_LOAD'}
    $("span.show").replaceWith('<div class="show">');
{/registerJs}
```

Tried this but it will simply output the whole snippet `{registerJs ...` as text on the page without adding it to the page's Javascript Code.

Similar commands like `registerJsFile` or `registerCss` aren't working either.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

As Mihai P. noted below, `{registerJs}` is syntax for Smarty templates. So, the question is: is there a similar way to register inline JS in Twig templates? The documentation only mentions registering assets.

Comment: does the file have a twig file extension so Yii knows to use twig to show it? It sounds like you are using a php file and expect it to be treated as twig.

Comment: No, the twig template itself is working, vars get replaced, loops, formatting etc. are all working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` in your Twig template, which is the current view, to call `registerJs`.

```
{% set script %}
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-widget',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
{% endset %}

{{ this.registerJs(script,4,'vue-widget') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is 3 years old, I put it here for someone runs into a similar problem.
You can use `this` in the Twig template with View constant like below:

```
{{ this.registerJs('$("span.show").replaceWith(\'<div class="show">\');', constant('\\yii\\web\\View::POS_HEAD')) }}
```

And, you can also call registerJs inside the Yii2 controller, which I think it makes the code cleaner

```
$this->getView()->registerJs('$("span.show").replaceWith(\'<div class="show">\');', \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is copied from the smarty section not the twig. There are some examples in the twig section that you might want to try.

Comment: Ouch, my bad. You're right, `{registerJs}` is syntax for Smarty templates. I'll edit my question.